# DropZone events not working - need a success call back

Tags: jquery, image, dropzone.js, jquery-events

I am using Dropzone along with Laravel. Currently the images are uploading fine to S3.

But I need to know a way that I can know when the file uploads are complete, and also get their url's back.

Currently this: (using the docs)

```
var token = "{!! csrf_token() !!}";
$("div#dropzoneFileUpload").dropzone({
    url: "/project/uploadImage",
    params: {
        _token: token
    }
});
Dropzone.options.dropzoneFileUpload = {
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 2, // MB
    accept: function(file, done) {

    },
    init: function() {
        this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
            alert("Added file.");
        });
    }
};
```

Doesn't alert anything when a file is added, nothing seems to be working in terms of events.

Any Help?

For reference this is the div that I create:

```
<div class='dropzone' id='dropzoneFileUpload'></div>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First you need to disable the dropzone auto discover, otherwise dropzone will load with the default options.

Second, probably the best is to set all the options before initializing the dropzone element or include all the options in the initialization itself, but not split them, because once the dropzone element is initialized i think it is not possible to change the options.

To retrieve the url's once the upload is complete, one way can be to send back the url to the browser as a response from the backend, then you can access that response using the `success` event.

Here an example:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

var token = "{!! csrf_token() !!}";

Dropzone.options.dropzoneFileUpload = {
    url: "/project/uploadImage",
    paramName: "file",
    maxFilesize: 2,
    params: {
        _token: token
    },
    init: function() {
        this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
            alert("Added file.");
        }),
        this.on("success", function(file, response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
    }
}

$('#dropzoneFileUpload').dropzone();
```

Comment: I can vouch that with Dropzone 4.3, you _do_ have to move the success callback initialization into the initialization of the Dropzone object, even though some other callbacks (specifically, dragenter, dragleave and drop) can be set _after_ initialization. Haven't dug into the code to see why...

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me, after a full day of struggling to get Dropzone to work within a jQuery wrapper. Baffling, but putting any events that rely on a `file` parameter won't get fired if they're declared outside of the `Dropzone.options` `init` function.